# How to I get a block to run once, but every time I bring up a the viewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Okay, so i thought I fixed the issue, but ran into another...

I take the user's location and then use their coordinates to find the zip code that they're currently in, but when I run it inside the block it logs out to the console only once. When I try to run the block in another method it spits out tons of times all with the same zip code.

My question is, how would I make it so the block prints one zip code, and it does it every time the view controller is brought up..?

```
//user's location
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];



        CLGeocoder *fgeo = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
        [fgeo reverseGeocodeLocation:locationManager.location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                zip = placemark.postalCode;

                NSLog(@"%@", zip);
                //[self jsonRequest];
```

Comment: to make it run when show view, put in ViewWillAppear. Not sure for part 2 of question.

Comment: It sort of depends on what you mean by "brought up" but `viewWillAppear` seems like a starting point.

Comment: Putting in ViewWillAppear fixed everything. Thanks you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override `viewDidAppear` and put your code in there. That is called *every* time the view controller appears. If you want it called only once when the view controller is created and is about to appear, override `viewDidLoad`.

If you want it to be called only once but specifically after the view is on the screen, you'll have to check for something in `viewDidAppear` that indicates if its appearing for the first time. You'll likely have to set a flag in `viewDidLoad` or `init` And then unset it once `viewDidAppear` is called the first time.

Answer (score 1):

> When I try to run the block in another method it spits out tons of
>   times all with the same zip code.

Once it enters the If(!error) put in a return statement, and that should solve problem.